# Opencv-Error while compiling libccv(static library)

Tags: opencv, clang, static-libraries, static-linking

I am getting this error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lccv
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

while compiling

```
clang -L"~/ccv/lib" -I"~/ccv/lib" sift.c -lccv `cat ~/ccv/lib/.deps`
```

(Here ccv/lib is a folder in my computer which contains library libccv.a)

Although I had given the path for finding static library libccv.a,compiler is checking it in /usr/bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find libraries in

> \usr\local\include\opencv

So compile using the following destination

Comment: Thanks for the answer